# Problems constructing a gridview of countdowntimers

Tags: java, android, gridview, timer, countdowntimer

So I have a gridlayout,

> activity_main.xml
>
> ```
>     <GridView
>         android:id="@+id/gridview"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
>         android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
>         android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
>         android:numColumns="4"
>         android:clickable="false" />
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

and inside of that layout I have specified a format for my grid cells

> grid_item.xml

```
<com.timer.app.ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="#55000000"
    />
```

The goal I'm trying to accomplish is on each grid item click, set its appropriate TextView to show a countdown from a time I set.

This is where I am stuck: I don't know how to create a count down timer that is relevant to each grid item, and how to detect which grid item is even being pushed.

I know the common response would probably be a link to the CountDownTimer documentation, which I have read and does not explain to me how to create say, an array of timers that I can make related to each griditem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can help with the countdown timer, but I know how to register which grid cell has been clicked.  In the past, I've done this by making each cell of the GridView a button, and adding a tag to each cell when it gets created.

calendar.xml

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:horizontalSpacing="-1px"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:verticalSpacing="-1px" >
</GridView>
```

gridcell.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gridcell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector_blue"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in java:

```
GridView calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
GridCellAdapter adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.gridcell);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);

public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
    public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super();
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null) {
                // ROW INFLATION
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridcell, parent, false);
            }
            gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.gridcell);
            gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);
            gridcell.setTag(R.id.TAG_ONE, 1);
    }

    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int value = (Integer) view.getTag(R.id.TAG_ONE);
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the help. What would the context for the inflator be though?

Comment: It's passed in to the GridCellAdapter via the constructor.  For the constructor call, I use getApplicationContext().